# Unauthorized 401 from `gem`

Tags: github, rubygems, bundler

```
$ gem install bundler:2.2.21
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Unauthorized 401 (https://bart_simpson:REDACTED@rubygems.pkg.github.com/private_org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler)
```

and

```
$ gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Unauthorized 401 (https://bart_simpson:REDACTED@rubygems.pkg.github.com/private_org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I've got a good personal token (good = full permissions, and not expired) set in two places:

```
$ cat ~/.bundle/config 
---
BUNDLE_RUBYGEMS__PKG__GITHUB__COM: "bart_simpson:ghp_nJabIP9JjPe7KOwgDrkiJextJggm114MZh7f"
BUNDLE_HTTPS://RUBYGEMS__PKG__GITHUB__COM/PRIVATE_ORG/: "bart_simpson:ghp_nJabIP9JjPe7KOwgDrkiJextJggm114MZh7f"
```

and

```
$ cat ~/.gem/credentials
---
:github: Bearer ghp_nJabIP9JjPe7KOwgDrkiJextJggm114MZh7f
```

Answer (score 2):

ah! After generating a new personal token and saving it in the two places mentioned in the Question, I forgot about a third place (which did the trick)...

```
$ cat ~/.gemrc 
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
- https://bart_simpson:ghp_nJabIP9JjPe7KOwgDrkiJextJggm114MZh7f@rubygems.pkg.github.com/private_org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

Docs: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-rubygems-registry#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token